# Java Spring Boot openApi How does Swagger populate the top page entry field

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui, swagger-3.0

Swagger UI has an entry field on top of it's page. I guess that this page is a link to the documentation.  Is this correct ?  And how can I change this value ?
I could already figure out that **/V1** is retrieved from application.yaml.

```
spring:
  application:
    ...
    api-version: "v1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All of these things are configured via properties.

Use the following keys ...

```
springfox:
  documentation:
    swaggerUi:
      baseUrl: /documentation
    openApi:
      v3:
        path: /documentation/v3/api-docs
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /documentation/v2/api-docs
```

You can also take a look at how they do it in the [examples](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos) repo from Swagger. Just import it into your IDE via VCS import and explore. You can pick up a lot of useful tips, hacks and best practices this way.

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: These are setups for Swagger SpringFox version I guess.   is this correct ?  I'm using openApi 3 with swagger 3.

Comment: Check out the answer below. I think it has the correct data. Swagger must have changed a bit since the last time I touched it

Answer (score 1):

For Springdoc, it is different application.properties that have to be applied:

```
springdoc.api-docs.groups.enabled=true
springdoc.api-docs.path= /v3/api-docs
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```